# How to change css html { } attribute for a single page

Tags: javascript, html, css

First time posting here. I was wondering how to change the css for the html { } attribute of a single page. I am trying to make the background color for 2 pages different. If there is a better way to do it please let me know. Thanks!

I have done this:

```
html {
  background-color: black;
}
```

for one page.

I want to do the same thing with a different color for another page (so that when you scroll out of bounds of the div it does not show a different color).

Comment: you can add Class in the body tag <body class="yourclass"> and change page background using this class.

Answer (score 0):

Every page must to take a different css external document:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/page1.css">
```

Then, you can change the element's properties:

```css
/* 1st page */
body{
  background-color: black;
  /* background: rgb(0,0,0); **You can also use this property** */
}

/* 2nd page 
body{
  background-color: blue;
}
*/
```

Saludos!

Comment: Or if he want to change just one page using external CSS that used in other pages, can add internal css in head of that page.

Answer (score 0):

This is one solution to your code. If you do not want the white part between two pages, just using *position:absolute;* in CSS.

Furthermore, your CSS code is not working because you forgot a "."

```css
.page1{
  height:100%;
  background:red;
}
.page2{
  height:100%;
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="page1">
    <p>
      Your elements
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="page2">
    <p>
      Your elements
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
```